# Energy States of 2D Harmonic Oscillator with cross-terms in the potential

Tags: quantum-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

How can I find the energy of a particle in a 2D potential of form $V(x,y)= \frac{k}{2}(3x^2 + 3y^2 + xy + yx)$? It looks to have a close relation with Quantum Harmonic Oscillators, is it related to it? What can we tell about the energy values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One should be able to diagonalize the hamiltonian so that in the new coordinates $(x' = f(x,y),y' = g(x,y))$ the Hamiltonian contains no cross terms. Then the spectrum will simply be two uncoupled harmonic oscillators with a frequency $k' = \alpha k$ where $\alpha$ is some constant.

Comment: Yes, I found the procedure. Thanks though!